# Prettier package not getting detected by WebStorm IDE

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide, prettier

I just started using WebStorm lately, and I always used Prettier for my projects inside VS Code, so I wanted to implement it here, but encountered a problem when WebStorm doesn't detect Prettier installation.

When I'm heading into `Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Prettier` I can't choose the package in "Prettier package" dropdown menu. Yeah I can link the installation myself, but every time I create a new project the settings are getting reset (as well with "Run with files") so it's not the way to go.

How can I fix the problem? I already checked node.js path, reinstalled Prettier using -G multiple times, updated node, but nothing helped me. Any solutions?

Comment: what OS are you on? Do you have Node installed with NVM?

Comment: I'm on win 10, i didn't had nvm installed, but i have now and nothing changed.

Comment: should be fixed in 2021.3.3 update, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-54501

Comment: It's broken again. I'm using 2022.1.4.

Answer (score 9):

globally install prettier:
`npm install --global prettier`

then from webstorm, go to Prettier preferences, insert this path under Prettier package: `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/prettier`

this is where your global node_modules are installed (not project level).

choose which files it should run for, insert `{**/*,*}.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}` for JS/ TS files.

[image]

Happy coding!

Comment: I want to add a comment here that if you use NVM and do a global install of prettier, prettier will end up in that version's node_modules folder, not the the folder HiLuit stated.  You can also use the UNIX command "which" and type "which prettier" at the command line to tell you where it is.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, I went to the appdata folder through a search in the system using the "%appdata%" key. Then to `npm > node_modules > prettier` folder and copied the folder path for Prettier package

[image: The path turned out like this]